Get edges with subdivision modifier active?
I'm trying to get edges when subdivision modifier is active.
Using depsgraph method gives the result as if the modifier had already been applied.
import bpy, bmesh

def get_mesh(obj):
    context = bpy.context
    depsgraph = context.view_layer.depsgraph
    object = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
    mesh = object.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=depsgraph)
    return mesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object

me = get_mesh(obj)
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

edges = [e for e in bm.edges]

bm.free()

I want to get this:

but I get these coordinates:

